# Azure Computer Vision enforces 4mb limit on Images in paid tier?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

I am currently working with Azure Computer Vision (read and anlyze APIs).

The docs state that images must be 4mb on free tier or up to 50mb on paid.

https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/computer-vision-v3-1-preview-1/operations/5d986960601faab4bf452005

Repro

Pricing Tier S1

```
POST 

https://{yourdomainy.cognitiveservices.azure.com/vision/v3.1/analyze?visualFeatures=Categories,Description,Tags

Headers
ocp-apim-subscription-key:{yourkey}
Content-Type:application/json

Body 
{"url":"{imageurl}"}
(i have also tried posting a byte array of the image - same result) All images are between 3-8mb, so far less than the 50mb limit stated in docs.

Reponse 

{\"code\":\"InvalidImageSize\",\"requestId\":\"177edee5-d17d-4fb7-a16f-da30644f77c4\",\"message\":\"Input image is too large.\"}
```

Any idea why this is happening?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Baced on your question you are getting this message also for 3MB images, therefore less than 4MB.

In addition to the MB constraint there is also a dimension constraint. The max dimension is 10000 x 10000 pixels.

It may be that you are getting a InvalidImageSize due to the dimension constraint.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I mentioned 3-8 range to show the size of images were not greater than the 50mb limit. I currently got success on files 3-4 but >4 return this error. I am unsure if there is another header or something I need to pass to bypass the 4mb limit from free tier? For info files are standard 1920x1900ish so not exceeding that limit.

Comment: It could be that you originally had used the free tier and the upgrade to paid tier has not taken effect.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW I just found this question and it did cause me some confusion too. I would just like to say that from my investigation you need to check each api individually for their size limites. It would seem that (as of api v3.1) many of the api's (Analyze and Describe) endpoints have a 4MB limit, with a couple of exceptions such as Read which call out 4MB limit on Free and 50MB on paid.

As the original post referred to Analyze endpoint in the example request I think this is likely the cause